# How to push subtree from git repo to Heroku using Github Actions?

Tags: git, github, heroku, continuous-integration, github-actions

I tried to push the subtree as a part of my Github repo that includes a frontend and a backend.
I am pushing the frontend folder or the backend folder using Github Actions to Heroku using this command : `git subtree push --prefix {folder} heroku master`

```
  name: HerokuCI

   on:
    push:
branches:
- master

jobs:
   build:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
strategy:
  matrix:
    os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest, macOS-latest]

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@master
- name: Login to Heroku 
  env: 
    HEROKU_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY }}
  run: heroku container:login 
- name: Build and push frontend
  env:
    HEROKU_FRONTEND_APP_NAME: ${{ secrets.HEROKU_FRONTEND_APP_NAME }}
  if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' && job.status == 'success'
  run: |
       heroku git:remote -a $HEROKU_FRONTEND_APP_NAME
       git subtree push --prefix frontend heroku master
- name: Build and push backend
  env:
    HEROKU_BACKEND_APP_NAME: ${{ secrets.HEROKU_BACKEND_APP_NAME }}
  if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' && job.status == 'success'
  run: |
       heroku git:remote -a $HEROKU_BACKEND_APP_NAME
       git subtree push --prefix backend heroku master
```

And it gave this error

git push using:  heroku master
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit: 1/1 (0) [0]
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

### [error]Process completed with exit code 128.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps. I used this for my workflow, current branch is dev and I am firing the action when a push to the branch occurs.

```
name: Staging deployment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v1

  - name: Add api remote origin
    run: |
      git remote add heroku-api https://heroku:${{ secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY }}@git.heroku.com/${{ secrets.HEROKU_SERVE_APP_NAME }}.git
  - name: Deploy api to Heroku
    run: |
      git subtree push --prefix server heroku-api master
  - name: Add frontend remote origin
    run: |
      git remote add heroku-frontend https://heroku:${{ secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY }}@git.heroku.com/${{ secrets.HEROKU_FRONTEND_APP_NAME }}.git
  - name: Deploy frontend to Heroku
    run: |
      git subtree push --prefix frontend heroku-frontend master
```

Ideally you could simplify this further by removing the step for setting a remote and use the url to Heroku directly at the deploy step.